# NDSolve with Infinite 1/0 Expression

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve this differential equation numerically.

```
a1 = 30; 
a2 = 10;
a3 = 10^-10;
xinit = 10^-10;
f1[x_] := 1/x;
f2[x_] := x^2;
f3[x_] := a1 + a2 *f1[x];
F1[x_] := (1 - 4 a3 π x^2 (f3[x] - f1[x]))/(1 - (2 a3 f2[x])/x);
F2[x_] := (4 π )/(
    1 - (2 a3 f2[x])/
     x)* (5 f3[x] + 9 f1[x] + (f3[x] + f1[x])*a2 - 3/(2 π x^2)) - 
   4 ((a3 (f2[x] + 4 π x^3 f1[x]))/(x^2 (1 - 2 a3 f2[x])))^2;


solutiony = 
 NDSolve[{x*y'[x] + y[x]^2 + F1[x]*y[x] + x^2*F2[x] == 0, y[0] == 2}, 
  y, {x, xinit, ∞}]
```

As output I get that infinite 1/0 expression are encountered. I have tried to vary the interval for x in case of singularities but this does not help. Can I rewrite the equations in a way Mathematica can solve them or can I maybe make some approximations that help?

Comment: You can't write `f3[x_]:=a1+a2*f3[x]` this will cause `TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]`  You should check your input before using it.

Comment: If you fixed the first error I get, `$RecursionLimit::reclim`, please show the corrected code. (You should start by fixing the first error you get, in case it causes the later ones.) Also, I suspect the BC `y[0] == 2`, which is evaluated at `x == 0.`, causes division by zero.

Comment: Hi, f3[x_]:=a1+a2*f1[x] is the correct definition. I am sorry, I made the mistake when trying to get from my code to the minimal required amount of code to show the problem. But even with that fixed, it does not work.

Comment: y[0]==2.00+eps for small eps does not work.

Comment: y[0]==2.00+eps still leads to evaluation at x=0, which causes the divide-by-zero error. you need to change to y[xinit]=2.00 or y[0+eps]=2.00, like Nasser shows. I pointed out y[0]=2 in case it was unintentional as well as because it caused the 1/0 error.